# Java HttpsServer and Session Resumption with TLSv1.2

Tags: java, ssl, https, tls1.2

I have setup a web server in Java using the `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsServer` class, but I am having trouble enabling session resumption with TLSv1.2. As far as I am aware, session resumption should be enabled by default in Java 11 (with support of Session Ticket Extension since Java 13 - [JDK-8223922](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8223922)) - I have tested this under both Java 11 and 13 without any luck.

When I try and scan my Java application using Qualys (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/), it reports "No (IDs assigned but not accepted)" for "Session resumption (caching)", which implies it isn't enabled.

I have also tested this with OpenSSL, which has the same behavior as it has a different Session-ID for each request, but with session resumption it should be able to re-use the same Session-ID:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:8443 -tls1_2 -reconnect -no_ticket | grep Session-ID
    Session-ID: 353DA62B469B16BB0156C366207AE4D4CD42A575AB94B376A0436B9AD7FE3D5F
    Session-ID: 0F30EB3EB602916D4B051BDC6887D81582C4698A63CE4F12FB5817AB0AC03CFB
    Session-ID: 6FA723129962DE82978A0ABF4345F4E4AD6E4987FFF3F9DA694BC7B5FF619A0F
    Session-ID: F5C43C5C627FB47C483087D5953DFF67912668019FF0A8235A0601E6E3C977E0
    Session-ID: 6E033003B9340BDBC97948546B4ED61AC4136E63203933E2D0A5A0DD2DC20408
    Session-ID: DE0BF90A519CA2854AC3AB87C138FF7D9EB27F420D0B75A88329725620206A6E
```

If I run the same test against "www.qualys.com", which does have session resumption enabled (update: they don't support Extended Master Secret Extension), then we can see the expected result:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.qualys.com:443 -tls1_2 -reconnect -no_ticket | grep Session-ID
    Session-ID: 58FF8EDA8BDD2A25905854C9AD2B19E1FE1549710CD8D86921A8A418D6877619
    Session-ID: 58FF8EDA8BDD2A25905854C9AD2B19E1FE1549710CD8D86921A8A418D6877619
    Session-ID: 58FF8EDA8BDD2A25905854C9AD2B19E1FE1549710CD8D86921A8A418D6877619
    Session-ID: 58FF8EDA8BDD2A25905854C9AD2B19E1FE1549710CD8D86921A8A418D6877619
    Session-ID: 58FF8EDA8BDD2A25905854C9AD2B19E1FE1549710CD8D86921A8A418D6877619
    Session-ID: 58FF8EDA8BDD2A25905854C9AD2B19E1FE1549710CD8D86921A8A418D6877619
```

I have put together the following SSCCE to demonstrate the problem - from what I have read, as long as my sessions all share a common `SSLContext` which is used to cache Session-IDs, then it should work. It requires a KeyStore to be present, which can be created using the following command:

```
keytool -storetype pkcs12 -storepass password -genkeypair -keyalg RSA -alias sscce -keystore sscce.p12 -validity 1825 -keysize 4096 -dname "CN=localhost" -ext san=dns:localhost -v
```

The following code should be placed into `SSCCE.java`:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.*;

public class SSCCE {
  public SSCCE() {
    try {
      KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
      ks.load(new FileInputStream("sscce.p12"), "password".toCharArray());

      KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
      kmf.init(ks, "password".toCharArray());

      TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
      tmf.init(ks);

      SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
      sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

      SSLParameters sp = sc.getDefaultSSLParameters();
      sp.setUseCipherSuitesOrder(true);

      sp.setProtocols(new String[] {
        "TLSv1.3", "TLSv1.2"
      });

      sp.setCipherSuites(new String[] {
        // -- TLSv1.3 Ciphers --
        "TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
        "TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
        // -- TLSv1.2 Ciphers --
        "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
        "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
        "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
        "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
        "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
        "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384",
        "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256",
        "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"
      });

      HttpsServer hs = HttpsServer.create(new InetSocketAddress("0.0.0.0", 8443), 0);
      hs.setHttpsConfigurator(new HttpsConfigurator(sc) {
        @Override
        public void configure(HttpsParameters p) {
          p.setSSLParameters(sp);
        }
      });
      hs.createContext("/", t -> {
        Headers h = t.getResponseHeaders();
        h.add("Content-Type", "text/plain");

        byte[] r = "Hello World!".getBytes();

        try (OutputStream o = t.getResponseBody()) {
          t.sendResponseHeaders(200, r.length);
          o.write(r);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      });

      ExecutorService httpThreadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
      hs.setExecutor(httpThreadPool);
      System.out.println("Listening on https://0.0.0.0:8443...");
      hs.start();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SSCCE();
  }
}
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8214037 seems related as by setting `jdk.tls.useExtendedMasterSecret=false` it allows session resumption to occur. It also looks like OpenSSL didn't include support for Extended Master Secret Extension (RFC 7627) until OpenSSL 1.1.0.

Comment: After some further digging, it appears the above code uses session resumption fine and the issue is with the client. If we test with OpenSSL 1.1.1 then it works without disabling Extended Master Secret Extension. Issue has been raised with Qualys as to why they don't detect RFC 7627 support. Although Session Ticket Extension (RFC 5077) was introduced with Java 13 - it was later disabled by default - enabled by setting `jdk.tls.server.enableSessionTicketExtension` to true.