# spring boot - undertow https session not expire or stop ssl handshake

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, https, undertow

I have an Undertow container for a Spring Boot application (Java 11) which is started using https.
The application is communicating with a IOS (Swift) and Android phone. I noticed that after not using the phone for a while
( 1 minute), the first request takes more time because the SSL handshake is performed.

I am wondering if there would be an option to cache/ invalidate the https session so that the first request after a longer period of time does not do the hanshake again.

Comment: What you are searching is the TLS session resumption. As far as I know Undertow uses the standard Java TLS implementation (SSLServerSocket) therefore this question should be the same as yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59378616/java-httpsserver-and-session-resumption-with-tlsv1-2

Comment: Should this be done on both client and server or is it enough on the server ?

Comment: I don't know. May be the server is enough, but if session resumption is available on Android and iOS and enabled by default is not known to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Robert's comment I will elaborate an answer.

I used

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose
```

to help me track the ssl handshakes.
Then, after seeing logs in the console I found out the classes responsible for the implementation of the TLS. Using debug I found this property for undertow. I think that for Tomcat should be similar.

`server.undertow.no-request-timeout` which I set in my **application.properties** to -1

No changes were required on the clients (phones: IOS and Android).